# How to iterate over the file content using Ant script?

Tags: ant

I need to read data from a file and do some further processing on that.

Actually I need to zip only those files which are modified. So prepared a `tracksheet.txt` which contains the list of all modified files in source code.

Read each file from the `tracksheet.txt` file, fetch it from svn and zip it.

Answer (score 9):

You could load the contents of the file using Ant's `loadfile` task. For example, assuming each entry is on a separate line, it would look something like this:

```
<loadfile
  property="changed.files"
  srcFile="tracksheet.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <striplinebreaks/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Then you can use Ant-Contrib's `for` or `foreach` task to loop over all the values in the property. For example:

```
<for list="${changed.files}" param="changedFile">
  <sequential>
    <echo>TODO fetch the file @{changedFile} from SVN</echo>
    <echo>TODO zip the file @{changedFile}</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Note that Ant-Contrib is not part of the standard install. You need a separate jar. Installation/usage instructions are on the website: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net

Comment: Was usefull for me but I additionally used <filterchain>
     **<suffixlines suffix=","/>**
      <striplinebreaks/>
    </filterchain> as the list in the for is expected to be comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Chris his answer:

```
<loadfile property="changed.files" srcFile="tracksheet.txt"/>

<for list="${changed.files}" param="changedFile" delimiter="${line.separator}">
  <sequential>
    <echo>@{changedFile}</echo>
  </sequential>
</for>
```